# Set code font style for words in table

Tags: tables, fonts, code

**MVP:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float} % Better figure and table placements
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\providecolor{keywords}{HTML}{aa5099}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering\sffamily\tabcolsep=2.5ex\relax
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{>{\color{keywords}}l>{\color{keywords}}l>{\color{keywords}}l>{\color{keywords}}l>{\color{keywords}}l}
        cond & in & not & boolean & break\\
        const & continue & decimal & default & define \\
        do & intersect & union & loop & infinity \\ 
        lambda & sum & division & pi & tau \\
        sin & cos & tan & int & float \\
        rational & real & complex&&
    \end{tabular}\par
    \end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I want a code like font, like when using `\texttt{}` or `\verb`. How can I set this in one place and affect all the values with the same font?

Comment: Is the entire table just a bunch of keywords, or do you have column headings and other content scattered throughout the `tabular`?

Comment: @Werner, there are **NO** main columns no nothing, except these keywords. Do you see the LaTeX code above? I posted everything, paste that inside Overleaf and it will output the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything inside the table should be handled the same, set the font (and colour) changes *outside* the `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\providecolor{keywords}{HTML}{aa5099}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5ex}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
  \footnotesize\ttfamily
  \color{keywords}%
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{l} }
    cond     & in        & not      & boolean & break    \\
    const    & continue  & decimal  & default & define   \\
    do       & intersect & union    & loop    & infinity \\ 
    lambda   & sum       & division & pi      & tau      \\
    sin      & cos       & tan      & int     & float    \\
    rational & real      & complex  &         &
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

<sub>You don't have to set the `tabular` inside a `table`. It can stand on its own as well.</sub>

Comment: THANK YOU, **Werner!**

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \providecolor{keywords}{HTML}{aa5099}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} *{5}{X[l, font=\ttfamily, fg=keywords]} @{}}}
cond        & in        & not       & boolean   & break     \\
const       & continue  & decimal   & default   & define    \\
do          & intersect & union     & loop      & infinity  \\
lambda      & sum       & division  & pi        & tau       \\
sin         & cos       & tan       & int       & float     \\
rational    & real      & complex   &           &
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, **Zarko!**